# Enlarge table/tabular without using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following table and I want to enlarge this. The width of the table has not to be big as the `\textwidth` but it should be a little bit larger as it usually is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[bthp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Parameter}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Messungen in ms}}                                  \\ \cline{3-5} 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1KB}   & A & 0,043                                 & 0,200                                              & 0,990                                       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 0,075                                  & 0,218                                                & 0,372                                          \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{100KB} & A & 4,059                               & 0,283                                              & 5,087                                       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 7,232                                  & 0,405                                                & 7,715                                          \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1MB}   & A & 37,989                              & 0,938                                             & 39,648                                      \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 38,600                                   & 1,445                                                & 40,122                                         \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{100MB} & A & 3652,048                            & 73,660                                            & 3726,602                                    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 3647,882                               & 115,198                                              & 3763,163                                       \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1GB}   & A & 36703,907                           & 738,011                                            & 37442,66                                    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 36326,751                              & 1117,514                                             & 37444,319                                      \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{4GB}   & A & 146859,876                            & 2815,443                                            & 149676,013                                    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 146340,339                             & 4363,830                                              & 150704,225                                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that it uses `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`. I created the table by using the tool http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables. Also, the position of the text in the cells should be centered and with `tabularx` I get left bounded text.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The table looks awful -- sorry ;-)

Comment: when I compiled your table (guessing the missing parts of your MWE) it was already 93% of the textwidth.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I changed it into an MWE, but it seems to use less space between the rows. Any suggestions how to make it more beauty? I mean...it is just a table :-)

Comment: @dcmst I changed it into an MWE and it doesn't look that it take 93% of the textwidth.

Comment: @user2514411 you are right, I made an error when copy/pasting (and the upvoter too, it seems :)). Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To widen the table to, say, `0.8\textwidth`, you could use a `tabular*` environment instead of the current `tabular` environment; use the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to make LaTeX expand the intercolumn whitespace sufficiently so that the table takes up the width specified in the first argument of `tabular*`.

You really ought to make a few more improvements to your table. I suggest you

- align the numeric data on the decimal marker (in this case, a comma rather than a period); this can be done with either the `dcolumn` package or the `siunitx` package. In the example below, I use a column type of `d{6.3}` for the three numeric columns.
- get rid of most `\cline` and `\hline` directives and use the macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule` -- to insert well-spaced lines to set off the header material and to mark the end of the table. The interior `\cline` directives can be dropped entirely; I'd use extra vertical whitespace instead of the interior `\hline`s.
- apply a few more touches to simplify and unify the visual appearance of the material

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[bthp]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{3}{d{6.3}} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Messungen in ms}}                                  \\ \cmidrule(l){3-5}
&   
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{First}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Second}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\textbf{Third}} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{1KB}   & A & 0,043                                 & 0,200                                              & 0,990                                       \\
                       & B & 0,075                                  & 0,218                                                & 0,372                                          \\[1.5ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{100KB} & A & 4,059                               & 0,283                                              & 5,087                                       \\
                       & B & 7,232                                  & 0,405                                                & 7,715                                          \\[1.5ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{1MB}   & A & 37,989                              & 0,938                                             & 39,648                                      \\
                       & B & 38,600                                   & 1,445                                                & 40,122                                         \\[1.5ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{100MB} & A & 3652,048                            & 73,660                                            & 3726,602                                    \\
                       & B & 3647,882                               & 115,198                                              & 3763,163                                       \\[1.5ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{1GB}   & A & 36703,907                           & 738,011                                            & 37442,66                                    \\
                       & B & 36326,751                              & 1117,514                                             & 37444,319                                      \\[1.5ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{4GB}   & A & 146859,876                            & 2815,443                                            & 149676,013                                    \\ 
                       & B & 146340,339                             & 4363,830                                              & 150704,225                                     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This uses a new column type `R` which will align the text (numbers) to the right within a 2.5cm parbox.

The showframe is just for the `\textwidth` comparison.

Other possibilities: Using a larger fontsize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{showframe}%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}


\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[bthp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc*{3}{R{2.5cm}}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Parameter}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Messungen in ms}}                                  \\ \cline{3-5} 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1KB}   & A & 0,043                                 & 0,200                                              & 0,990                                       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 0,075                                  & 0,218                                                & 0,372                                          \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{100KB} & A & 4,059                               & 0,283                                              & 5,087                                       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 7,232                                  & 0,405                                                & 7,715                                          \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1MB}   & A & 37,989                              & 0,938                                             & 39,648                                      \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 38,600                                   & 1,445                                                & 40,122                                         \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{100MB} & A & 3652,048                            & 73,660                                            & 3726,602                                    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 3647,882                               & 115,198                                              & 3763,163                                       \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1GB}   & A & 36703,907                           & 738,011                                            & 37442,66                                    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 36326,751                              & 1117,514                                             & 37444,319                                      \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{4GB}   & A & 146859,876                            & 2815,443                                            & 149676,013                                    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                       & B & 146340,339                             & 4363,830                                              & 150704,225                                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before anybody complains about the lines: I did not address that issue ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Grouping the rows avoids using `\multirow`; particularly the header “Parameter” shouldn't be lowered, because it's first level like “Messungen in ms”. An empty cell is interpreted as “repeat the value above”.

For the spacing, add `\hspace{...}` between columns; adjust to suit the value of 3em I set.

Using `siunitx` allows for properly aligning the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[bthp]
\sisetup{group-four-digits} % in the table the four digit numbers should be like the longer ones

\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  c@{\hspace{3em}}
  S[table-format=6.3]@{\hspace{3em}}
  S[table-format=4.3]@{\hspace{3em}}
  S[table-format=6.3]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Messungen in \si{ms}}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
&& {\textbf{First}} & {\textbf{Second}} & {\textbf{Third}} \\
\midrule
1\,KB   & A &      0,043 &    0,200 &      0,990 \\
        & B &      0,075 &    0,218 &      0,372 \\
\midrule
100\,KB & A &      4,059 &    0,283 &      5,087 \\
        & B &      7,232 &    0,405 &      7,715 \\
\midrule
1\,MB   & A &     37,989 &    0,938 &     39,648 \\
        & B &     38,600 &    1,445 &     40,122 \\
\midrule
100\,MB & A &   3652,048 &   73,660 &   3726,602 \\
        & B &   3647,882 &  115,198 &   3763,163 \\
\midrule
1\,GB   & A &  36703,907 &  738,011 &  37442,660 \\
        & B &  36326,751 & 1117,514 &  37444,319 \\
\midrule
4\,GB   & A & 146859,876 & 2815,443 & 149676,013 \\
        & B & 146340,339 & 4363,830 & 150704,225 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]